# Implementing ThreeJS Transform control to Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to include ThreeJS Transform control into my Forge Viewer, using this tutorial:

https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/moving-visually-your-components-in-the-viewer-using-the-transformtool.html

Currently I am able to insert the Transform Control into the viewer, but cannot interact with it. In my code, I have to change a bit from the tutorial. Instead of adding overlay, I'm adding a scene and then add the Transform Control using viewer.impl.addMesh(TransformControl). For some reason unknown, add overlay doesn't work.

Are extra steps required to interact with meshes in different scene than the main scene? Here is my code snippet:

```js
const transformControlTx: TransformControls =
      new THREE.TransformControls(viewer.impl.camera, viewer.impl.canvas, "scale");
transformControlTx.setSize(cube.geometry.boundingSphere.radius * 5);
transformControlTx.addEventListener('change', reRender);
if (!viewer.overlays.hasScene('CubeTranformScene')) {
      viewer.overlays.addScene('CubeTranformScene');
}
transformControlTx.attach(cube);
viewer.overlays.addMesh(transformControlTx, 'CubeTranformScene');
```

I would like to have this transform control to be able to control the scale of the cube I attached, which is also a custom ThreeJS Mesh

Answer (score 2):

The same tool is implemented and demoed in https://forge-extensions.autodesk.io/?extension=TransformationExtension

Code: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/tree/master/public/extensions/TransformationExtension

Comment: Thank you. How can I use that Transformation Control to change scale instead of Translate currently? In ThreeJS Demo, I just need to pass a render callback to the control, and set the mode to "Scale" when creating the control

Comment: scaling of objects is demonstrated in this example https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/tree/master/public/extensions/DrawToolExtension

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I'm using Typescript, and following the github example. However, my new class cannot extends ToolInterface, I can only implements. Can you please help?